# popup alert - search loop

Tags: python, selenium, find, click, popupwindow

I am a beginner so the question may be strange :)

I want to test the Main Menu of the website "https://tvn24.pl/"

I am looking for elements, I put them into the list and then iterating through it opening each page found - Works fine

Now step two:
On only two pages(https://kontakt24.tvn24.pl/ and https://tvn24.pl/ ) a window pops up in which you should click the "consent" button.

It is a completely different confirmation dialog for each page (different xpath, Id, etc.)

I would like to write functions (loops)
Which will be checked for 5 seconds if the window appeared, if so, click the accept button.
I would like this function to check both cases of "alert".
If a window "A" pops up - Click Accept - end of function
If a "B" window pops up instead of "A" - Click Accept - end of function
If no window pops up, do nothing.

Attention :

1. These popups are elements that cover the entire page.
2. These are not allerts or frames - ordinary "DIV" so you can't use swith to alert or frame
3. I know, I can also use a try:

Any hints?
Loop while with if, elif?

I tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
def alert_accept_if_with_Wait_V2(driver):
    V1_alert_window_Id = "onetrust-banner-sdk"
    V1_accept_button_Id = 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler'

    V2_alert_frame_Id = "rodoLayer"
    V2_accept_button_Xpath = './/*[@id="rodoLayer"]//a[@class="rodoFooterBtnAccept"]'

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5, poll_frequency=0.5)

    if wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, V1_alert_window_Id))):
        wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, V1_accept_button_Id))).click()
        print(f"On page {driver.current_url} onetrust alert accepted")
    elif wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, V2_alert_frame_Id))):
        wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, V2_accept_button_Xpath))).click()
        print(f"On page {driver.current_url} old alert accepted")
    else:
        print(f"On page {driver.current_url} no alert appeared ")
```

Another :

```
def alert_accept_if_with_Wait_V1(driver, max_seconds_to_wait=5):

V1 = './/*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"] '
V2 = './/*[@id="rodoLayer"]//a[@class="rodoFooterBtnAccept"]'

seconds = 0
while range(max_seconds_to_wait):
    if driver.find_element_by_xpath(V1 or V2):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(V1 or V2).click()
        return False
    else:
        seconds += 1
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print(f"On page {driver.current_url} no alert appeared ")
```

Comment: Could you include the information of the link? that way the info will not get lost if other people will revisit the question when the site goes down.

Comment: It looks like your code is incorrectly indented, which matters in Python. Specifically, it looks like every line other than the first one (`def`) in each snippet needs to be indented one (more) level. Is your code indented as it appears to be, or did the indentation just not copy over correctly?

Comment: Yes.. Copy/Paste Error :):

Answer (score 0):

```
seconds = 0
while seconds < 3:
    V1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
    V2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="rodoLayer"]//a[@class="rodoFooterBtnAccept"]')
    if len(V1) > 0:
        V1[0].click()
        print(f"On page {driver.current_url} onetrust alert accepted")
        return False
    elif len(V2):
        V2[0].click()
        print(f"On page {driver.current_url} old alert appeared")
        return False
    else:
        seconds += 1
        time.sleep(1)
else:
    print(f"On page {driver.current_url} no alert appeared ")
    return False
```